# Determine the base and translate it to base 10.

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

$((((/////$ & $*(((/// = **((//$

Where (, / and * are digits, & is some operation and = is equals, determine what base this statement is in, what operation & is and translate it to base 10.

From looking at it, the first number has 9 digits, second has 7 and the result has 6 digits. Lets say base is b.

This means the operation cannot be $ + $ or $\times$ as the result has a less digits than the other two numbers.

This also means the operation cannot be $-$ as the lower bound of the first number, $b^8$ minus the upper bound of the second number, $b^7-1$ is always going to be greater than the upper bound of the third number, $b^6-1$

In other words, $b^8-(b^7-1) > (b^6-1) \Leftrightarrow b^8 > b^7 +b^6-1$

This also means the operation cannot be $\div$ as the lower bound of the first number, $b^8$ divided by the upper bound of the second number, $b^7-1$ is always going to be smaller than the upper bound of the third number, $b^6-1$

In other words, $\frac{b^8}{b^7-1} <b^6-1 \Leftrightarrow b^8<b^{13}-b^7-b^6+1$

Therefore, one of the only viable operations left is the modulo. However, I have no idea how to continue this.
[image: attached picture of question]

UPDATE: question is wrong, ill edit in the right question when i get to it.

Comment: What are the possible operations for &?

Comment: It was not given

Comment: Then the question cannot be answered because I can define any operation that will give the required result.

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ different digits? Or can they be the same?

Comment: I think we can assume that the operations would likely be something that a first year student would know, so the basic mathematical operations and modulo(?)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon yes, they are unique digits

Comment: I just want to make sure, before I attempt this question, that it actually *is* a valid question and not something fabricated to confuse people, and in the end having no solution. What is the source of this question?

Comment: A bonus question for one the assignments in a math course in university

Comment: @h4ppyturt1e I am convinced with your logic that the $\&$, if it were one of $\pm , \times , \div$ or $\mod{}$, has to be the mod (so I up vote, +1) but can you attach the PDF in the comments below, because I'd like to convince myself that $\&$ can be nothing else (e.g. a bitwise operation).

Comment: sure, ill attach the original

Comment: @h4ppyturt1e Thank you. My next contribution should be the answer(If I get it!)

Comment: I could totally see this as a misleading question where $( = 0$.

Comment: yeah I think that very well could be the case

Comment: Along those lines, if I set $*=0$ I could get a multiplication problem! Maybe this could work.

Comment: A correction: the upper bound of a number with $k$ digits in base $b$ is

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} (b-1)b^j = (b-1)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}b^j = b^k - 1.$$

This does not change the conclusions regarding the possibilities for the operations, but it's worth noting.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri thank you, will include in edit!

Comment: I got till $$(b+c-a)\x\equiv b \ (\mathrm{mod}\ \n+1)$$ where $\x$ is a number and $\n$ is the base. $($, $/$ and $*$ are $a$, $b$ and $c$ respectively.$\newcommand{\x}{\color{red}{x}}$
$\newcommand{\n}{\color{blue}{n}}$